# Webscraping with R JSON

Tags: r, web-scraping

I want to get the names of the companies  by two columns **Region** and **Name of role-player**. I find `json` links on each page already, but with `RJSonio` it didnt work. It's collect data, but how could I get it to a readable view? Could anybody help, thanks.

Here is the [link](http://www.milksa.co.za/registered_unregistered)

I try this code from another similiar question on Stackoverflow

```
library(RJSONIO)

library(RCurl)
```

## grab the data

```
raw_data <- getURL("http://www.milksa.co.za/admin/settings/mis_rest/webservicereceive/GET/index/page:1/regionID:7.json")
#Then covert from JSON into a list in R
data <- fromJSON(raw_data)

length(data)

final_data <- do.call(rbind, data)

head (final_data)
```

Comment: You need to show some code that you are trying to get working so that we can help you get it back on track.

Comment: @bethanyP got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal preference for this is to use the library `jsonlite` and not use `fromJSON` at all

```
require(jsonlite)
data<-jsonlite::fromJSON(raw_data, simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)
finalData<-data.frame(cbind(data$rolePlayers$RolePlayer$orgName, data$rolePlayers$Region$RegionNameEng))
colnames(finalData)<-c("Name", "Region")
```

Which gives you the following data frame:

```
                                   Name       Region
                GoodHope Cheese (Pty) Ltd Western Cape
                       Jay Chem (Pty) Ltd Western Cape
                Coltrade International cc Western Cape
 GC Rieber Compact South Africa (Pty) Ltd Western Cape
                    Latana Cheese Pty Ltd Western Cape
                       Marco Frischknecht Western Cape
```

A great way to visualize how to query and what is in your JSON string can be found here:[Chris Photo JSON viewer](http://chris.photobooks.com/json/)

You can just cut and paste it in there from the `raw_data` (removing external quotation marks). From there it becomes easy to see how to structure your data using addressing like you would with a traditional data frame and the `$` operator.

Comment: That is awesome! Thank you BethanyP!