# Extracting from result

Tags: r

I did some type of webscraping with following code:

```
library(RJSONIO)
library(RCurl)

# grab the data
raw_data <- getURL("http://www.milksa.co.za/admin/settings/mis_rest/webservicereceive/GET/index/page:1/regionID:7.json")

# Then convert from JSON into a list in R
data <- fromJSON(raw_data)
length(data)

# data.frame
final_data <- do.call(rbind, data)
head(final_data)
glimpse(final_data)
```

After that, it shows list of information, but how can I extract exact type of names and region from it? How set it by 2 columns Name and Region?

Comment: Please share a reproducible example of `final_data`

Comment: @Sotos sorry, it's already done. This is really help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42800994/webscraping-with-r-json By the way, thank you.